# Django rest framework partial update with where query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I just want to update two fields of table where id_payment = 1. How to do it? It showing me the error bellow. 
IntegrityError at /receivePendingPayment/
(1048, "Column 'bank_id' cannot be null")

```
#View

    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    @api_view(['PATCH'])
    def receivePendingPayment(request):
        id_payment = request.data['id_payment']
        data = {'accountant_received_by': request.user.id, 'accounts_status': 'Received'}

        BankPaymentHistory.objects.filter(id=id_payment)
        serializer = BankPaymentUpdateSerializer(data=data, partial=True, many=False)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    #Serializer

    class BankPaymentUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BankPaymentHistory
        fields = ('accounts_status','accountant_received_by')

    #Model

    class BankPaymentHistory(models.Model):
        activation_enum = (('Active', 'Active'), ('Deactive', 'Deactive'))
        accounts_status_enum = (('Pending', 'Pending'), ('Received', 'Received'))
        bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        file = models.ForeignKey(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        salesperson = models.ForeignKey(SalesPerson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        paymentmode = models.ForeignKey(PaymentModes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        chequeno = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        chequedate = models.DateField()
        paymentdate = models.DateField()
        remark = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        accountant_received_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_accountant_received_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
        accountant_received_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
        create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
        activation_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=activation_enum, default='Active')
        accounts_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=accounts_status_enum, default='Pending')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an instance to the serializer, so it can know that it should do an update.

```
 instance = BankPaymentHistory.objects.filter(id=id_payment).first()
 serializer = BankPaymentUpdateSerializer(instance=instance, data=data, partial=True, many=False)
```

Comment: Showing this error
`AttributeError at /receivePendingPayment/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`